# Can I re-weight the a training data set to make it more relevant in the selection of algorithms for use on a slightly different data set?

Tags: accuracy, boosting, supervised-learning, resampling, bagging

Suppose $(x_i,y_i)$ constitutes supervision data. Assume a collection of statistical methods which could be trained on one subset and ranked by their accuracy on another subset of this data (according to some loss function).

But we are not going to train directly on $(x_i,y_i)$. Instead suppose $(x_k,y_k)$ is a different set of supervision data intended to be similar to the original. For instance, the original data $(x_i,y_i)$ might comprise survey results from one city whereas $(x_k,y_k)$ might denote the exact same survey carried out in another city. I care ultimately about is how well methods perform on the first set of data, but I can only provide the second to my collaborators. They create approaches and submit. I alone am able to try them on the original data set.

As I can discern privately how each point in the second data set helps predict performance of a given method on the first, I would be very tempted to re-points in the second data set $(x_k,y_k)$ or perhaps just remove some data point in order that the ranking of methods on the second data set, which my colleagues have visibility one, better reflects the ranking of methods on the primary data set.

Does this sound reasonable? One could imagine an iterative scheme vaguely analogous to boosting. Where should I be looking in the literature for something similar?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you have conceptualized the problem in the best way.  Instead of preparing to be surprised when a predictive model developed in one region doesn't work well in another, create a unified model that includes parameters capturing geographical variation in outcome.  For more information see http://www.fharrell.com/2017/01/split-sample-model-validation.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Your point is taken well. However whether I use bootstrapping or split sample I'm still tempted to try a re-weighting of the secondary data set so that it does a better job of bubbling the best methodologies to the top, where "best" is defined as most appropriate for use on the primary data set.

Comment: At first glance that does not seem to be based on statistical principles.